# java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: "file name" while selecting file from file manager. android studio

Tags: android-studio

This is my select file code where i am selecting file using uri class and sending the file path and uri object to the Filepath class.

when i am trying to select from download section it throws the **numberformatexception:for input string:"file name "**. please help me to solve this error as i am trying to store the file into the database

SelectFile.java

```
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
    uri = data.getData();
    String uriString = uri.toString();
    File myFile = new File(uriString);

    PdfNameHolder = myFile.getName();

    PdfPathHolder = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
  }
```

Here i am selecting the contents of the file

FilePath.java

```
public class FilePath
    {

      public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)
      {
    //check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }

        //DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            try {
                //error is in this block
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                Toast.makeText(context, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int l = Integer.parseInt(id.trim());
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), l);

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error1 : "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Error : "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        finally{
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

       private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
}
```

Comment: hey. do you get the solution ?